Equivalence of two definitions of revealed preference
Given a choice structure $(\mathscr{B},C(.))$ we can construct a preference align with this structure, write it as $\succcurlyeq^C$ defined as $$x\succcurlyeq^C y\Leftrightarrow \exists B \in \mathscr{B},st. x,y \in B, x\in C(B)$$
This is the definition given in MWG. But I find another definition somewhere else.
$$x\succcurlyeq^C y \Leftrightarrow x\in C(\{x,y\})$$
Are they equivalent?
2 to 1 is easy. We take $B=\{x,y\}$.
1 to 2?
I notice if the choice structure satisfies WARP then 1 implies 2. But if not, then we don't have equivalence? Any clarification?

If $\mathcal{B}$ contains only sets with three or more elements, then there is no connection at all.
